# Laravel Relationship between Three Models

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

```
sold_items:
id    order_id   customer_id   name      
--    --------   -----------   ----
1     5          14            An object

orders:
id      po_num
--      ------
...     ...
5       123


customers:
id      name
--      ----
...     ...
14      John Doe
```

A `SoldItem` has an `order_id` and a `customer_id`.

I'm trying to define a **`hasOne`** relationship between an `Order` and its `Customer` through the `SoldItem` without having to insert a `customer_id` column in the `Order` model's table.

**`hasOneThrough`** seemed to be the solution but I couldn't figure out where to go from there, or is that even the answer?

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Order extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function sold_items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\SoldItem');
    }

    public function customer()
    {
        // return $this->hasOneThrough();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making the `Customer` an `attribute` of the `Order` through its `sold_items` with:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Order extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $guarded = ['id'];

    public function sold_items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\SoldItem');
    }

    public function getCustomerAttribute()
    {
        return $this->sold_items->first()->customer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for Customer model

```
{

    public function sold_items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\SoldItem');
    }


}
```

for Order model

```
{

    public function sold_items()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\SoldItem');
    }


}
```

for SoldItem model

```
{

    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsto('App\Cutomer');
    }

     public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsto('App\Order');
    }

}
```

I prefer working on their relationship first then and use with() function to get their values.

```
use App\Customer;

$customer = Customer::with('sold_items','sold_items.order')->get();
```